# Header position inside div

Tags: html, css, web

Apparently the text is positioned to the right and I do not know why. Earlier the header was working but now it does not.

[image]

```
.news-box {
    background: black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translate(20%, 50%);
    border-radius: 20px; 
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px 10px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.news-box > h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px rgb(0,0,0,1);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(0,0,0,0.8);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't have the full code (including html), i can only suggest to put the text inside a `<span>text</span>` and use styling of `float:left` (for example).

Another option would be to put it inside a `<span>` or a `<div>` and set `"text-align:left/right"` (whatever works for you)

Comment: Thing is when I do that it turns out like this
http://prntscr.com/shg11o

Comment: try and check if the container div has padding-left (seems like it).

Comment: Here is the whole css code for that page

https://pastebin.com/hKcKXAXa

Comment: And here is the div that contains those elements https://pastebin.com/69ax8ZjG